# RPi.GPIO interrupt

Tags: gpio, python, interrupts

Is there any way to pass args to the callback function when using

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)
```

Comment: I don't use the Python libraries for programming my Pis, but in the other languages I do use, no, you cannot. You should however be able to set up some global variables and access them from within your ISR though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about RPi.GPIO but Joan's `pigpio` library also offers callbacks so I will try to explain how this could be achieved with `pigpio` as an example assuming the technique can be transferred to RPi.gpio (after all it's just Python doing the trick).

[`functools.partial(func, *args, **keywords)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) can solve this task: *Return a new partial object which when called will behave like func called with the positional arguments args and keyword arguments keywords.*

**Syntax of [pigpio's](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#callback) `callback(user_gpio, edge, func)`:**

> Calls a user supplied function (a callback) whenever the specified GPIO edge is detected.
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> user_gpio:= 0-31.
>      edge:= EITHER_EDGE, RISING_EDGE (default), or FALLING_EDGE.
>      func:= user supplied callback function.
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> import pigpio
> pi = pigpio.pi()
>
> def cbf(gpio, level, tick):
>     print(gpio, level, tick)
>
> cb1 = pi.callback(22, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, cbf)
> ```

**Using functool.partial() to reduce the argument list:**

```
from functools import partial

def cbf_with_argument(gpio, level, tick, myarg):
    print(gpio, level, tick, myarg)

cb1 = pi.callback(22, 
                  pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, 
                  partial(cbf_with_argument, myarg=4))
```

This sets up the callback with myarg set to 4. `partial` also handles `*args, **kwargs` argument lists in a similar fashion the example above uses just one argument for simplicity.